# I want to replace the trim kit in my shower without replacing the valve

Tags: shower, trim, valve

We have very outdated hardware in our shower that we want to change out.  The name stamped on the handle is Signature, which I believe is a Kohler product.  I want to change out the trim without changing any of the plumbing.  Do I need to buy a Kohler product or is there another brand that will work with the current pluming? The previous homeowner saved the installation guide which says the valve is Rite-Temp pressure balancing valve.

Comment: This skates near a 'shopping question', which isn't exactly what this site is for, but... in the big box stores you'll find 'universal trim kits', that do exactly what you want. They aren't brand specific. The problem with them is that they aren't universal. I've had maybe 3/4 work and the remainder get returned.